# Wpf calendar change header background

Tags: wpf, xaml, calendar, header, background

How to change header background of a calendar control? I need only top, not all area.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this MSDN article that goes through the process of customizing the WPF Calendar Control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx#id0430016

It includes steps for setting a custom template for the control.

Comment: Thank you, i had seen the article but i dont know what template need. Do I need to re-define all the templates to change only the color of the header?

Comment: Thanks, finally i must redefined calendar style completly. Its necessary see code xaml of calendar.